# How to create a editable dictionary for google chrome extension?

Tags: dictionary, google-chrome-extension

I am a data collector, let me try to make make myself clear enough for you since I'm not a coder.

I wish to create a dictionary (for chrome extension) that I can put my own words to it then get the definitions whenever me and my team needed. This dictionary can be easily to add up new words (by me and my team), and get definitions by select the word (or a phrase) and trigger a keyboard (like Alt + D) to open a small window to see.

Just as simple as Goggle dictionary is fine for me.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en

I have no idea where to begin with, all I wanna ask is the easiest ways and the tools to do this and then I will try to search on the internet. Do I need a website to store data? How can my team and me add words altogether?

Please share if you have any idea.
Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to setup some Javascript that handles the selected word, and you could either compare it to a local dictionary there's published through updates on the extension or on a file on a server. I'm no expert in data handeling, but I'd guess that one of the ways you could do it was to write the dictionary in JSON.

So yeah, my guess is: Javascript for handeling the selected words and comparing it to the dictionary, and JSON for storing the dictionary.

And no, it would be required to have a server for storing the data, but it would probably make the process of updating the data a bit easier. If you were to get a server for storage, you could simply add words to the dictionary in a simple chrome extension popup where the users would type the word, and the description of the word.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am going to give it a try with your suggestion.